# Meteor : Accounts onCreateUser

Tags: meteor

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
  if (options.password.length < 6 && options.password.length != 0) {
    throw new Meteor.Error();
  } else if (options.password.length == 0) {
    throw new Meteor.Error();
  } else {
    user.password = options.password;
  }
});
```

Simple server-side validation.

Here's my create user call:

`Accounts.createUser({email:email,username:username,password:password,profile:{firstname:firstname,lastname:lastname}},function(error){});`

Without the server-side validation, it works smoothly.

and the  problem is... it says length of undefined when I use the onCreateUser.

I guess the .length is the problem. But I need it.
any workarounds?

Comment: Can you log user and options and see what they contain.

Comment: Yes. I also tried to remove the password validation (server-side) and validate the other fields and it worked. But when I try to validate the password on the onCreateUser, meteor gives me length of undefined.

Comment: Why do you need the password?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  The password is explicitly `deleted` in the code.

```
// Attempt to log in as a new user.
Accounts.createUser = function (options, callback) {
  options = _.clone(options); // we'll be modifying options

  if (!options.password)
    throw new Error("Must set options.password");
  var verifier = SRP.generateVerifier(options.password);
  // strip old password, replacing with the verifier object
  delete options.password;
  options.srp = verifier;
```

Comment: It was defined. I successfully insert accounts before ( without the server validating it first but has a client-side validation ). I guess the .length of javascript doesn't function.

Comment: Accounts.createUser({email:email,username:username,password:password,profile:{firstname:firstname,lastname:lastname}},function(error)
    {}):

Comment: @o2kevin the password isn't passed down to onCreateUser because it is encrypted using SRP. It is not possible to retrieve the password. You can see the password in encrypted form at `user.services.password` if you console.log it during `onCreateUser`.

Answer (score 0):

The `options` object has the following structure:

```
{
    username: 'dummy',
    email: 'dumm@example.com',
    password: {
        digest: '7d1a54127b222502f5b79b5fb0803061152a44f92b37e23c6527baf665d4da9a',
        algorithm: 'sha-256'
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `password` field is an object with a digest (a hash) so you can't retrieve the password on the server (nor can you test for its length).

---

It seems like you subsequently asked another question on [how to check password length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173724/password-length-checking-meteorjs) in the server. The answer to which backs up the fact that you can't.