# Meteor - Validate user password on server on new user creation

Tags: meteor

After calling `Accounts.createUser()` I'd like to validate password string on the server (that it is of allowed length and so forth..).
As far as I know, meteor sends SHA256 hash to the server instead of plaintext.
So is there a way to lookup that hash and get a plaintext password on the server?
More generally: is there a way to validate a password server side?

**Update**
After reading on hashes (link supplied in comments) and some more research I've understood there's no way to lookup a hash, plus g I've found out that sha256 string can encode terabytes of string input, but is always 64chars in length itself.
So no need to worry about password length bytesize in DB. Good to know =)

Comment: No, that would make salting and hashing the password completely pointless!

Comment: Why is that? I mean, if the server matches user password against user record on login, I can surely mimic that when creating user, no?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you're asking. Start by reading http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure; the whole point is that the process is **one way**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor - How to use use server side validation on password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139108/meteor-how-to-use-use-server-side-validation-on-password)

Comment: Validate the password strength on your registration page. Don't allow the user to submit the registration form until email address and password strength have been verified. Don't involve the server.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks, mate! Now I know a bit about hashing and salting =) And my original question was incorrect itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to have plaintext passwords on the server.  If you did that, you could technically store the password as plaintext instead of hashing it, which is a security no-no.

If you really wanted to do this (and I don't recommend it), you would have to remove the accounts-password package and roll your own (insecure) authentication.