# Password Length Checking Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

How can I check at least the password length from the server submitted by the client? 
I know that password is not sent plain over the wire and thus I'm wondering on how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password data is only communicated through hashes so, as you mentioned, the server never sees the user's password during a key exchange. The server can create the user with a password but that string would have to be transmitted somehow.

Your best bet is to have the length checked in your signup form. I realize client code can't be trusted, however it seems unlikely that a motivated hacker is going to modify the source just to have a weak password.

Comment: You have a point but I wonder if meteor will at least somehow support or fix that issue...

Comment: [Yes, they will](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js#L76).